# Nearest-neighbor: how are different dimensions weighted or scaled?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose I wanted to predict the total energy consumption for individual cities. The independent variables I have are a) the population size for each city, b) the number of art galleries in each city, and c) the number of letters in the name of each city (so "New York" has a score of seven). For these cities I also have the dependant variable: total energy consumption for each city.

But now I have some other cities, where I know what a), b), and c) are but I do not know what their energy consumption is, and want to predict it using nearest-neighbours.

How would nearest-neighbours adjust the scale or weight given to dimensions b) and c)? Or does it just give equal weight and scale to all dimensions regardless?

In this example it is obvious that b) and c) are unhelpful and a human would intervene to edit them out, but in other situations it may not be so obvious.

Comment: Energy consumption is a continuous variable, nearest neighbor is not really meant to output continuous variables. Do you have any particular reason why you don't want to do a regression?

Answer (score 1):

Nearest neighbours does not scale your data, but you should do it before hand. Whatever distance function you use, it will be (negatively) affected by features having different scalings.

For example, assume you are using the Euclidean distance. If one feature is measured in milimeters and has values in that order of magnitude, and a second one is measured in meters (with that order of magnitude too), then the second one will dominate the result of the distance function.

A standard procedure is to scale your features (see, for example, the Wikipedia site on [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling), or this [blog](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html)).